# Power up Arduino using AC/DC Adapter

Tags: power, adapter

Wanna get your advice regarding powering up Arduino Uno using AC/DC Adapter to the barrel jack.

The first adapter I use couldn't work and the shop which I bought it from said the adapter was short circuit-ed.

Out of goodwill, she replace it for free and I tested it out again. The first few tries it worked perfectly fine but stopped working (suspected short-circuited again).

The adapter output is DV9V - 2A.

The circuit consists of 2 ultrasonic sensor and 1 buzzer.

I am quite sure the Arduino circuit does not draw more than 2A of current.

Any idea what's the issue? Thanks!

EDIT - [image]

I've uploaded a photo of the schematic done using Tinkercad. I am using a different breadboard thus the configuration as shown.

Comment: As you suspect a short circuit, have you checked for that? Also: Are you sure, that the power supply is broken? Or is it the Arduino? The barrel jack is connected to a voltage regulator, which will go into emergency shutdown, if you draw more current through it, than supported, (for genuine Arduinos).  Cheap clones might get their voltage regulator destroyed. Please show your real circuit, so that we can check for a short circuit

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the system. 2 failed power supplies in a row seems suspicious. I would try to rule out a problem with your Arduino or with your circuit. Buy a multi-tester and measure the voltage out of your power supply, and the resistance of your circuit. You might want to add a 2A fuse to your power supply to protect it. (You'd need a male and a female barrel jack connector, a fuse holder, some wire, and a soldering iron.)

Comment: Switch-mode based DC adapters virtually _have_ to have short circuit protection and OCP to pass UL certification (otherwise it would fail). Most smps driver chips have that built-in as well, so if it's a recently made adapter, that's probably not the issue.

Comment: Hi @chrisl I have uploaded a photo of the schematic. Can you help to take a look? The Arduino works perfectly fine because it is able to power up via USB. I am supplying a 2A into the Arduino which requires only 1A. I read on forum that supplying more current is fine

Comment: @DuncanC Hi, I've tested the adapter, it doesn't have any voltage output. So pretty sure the adapter is damaged. I'm trying to find out why the adapter is damaged

Comment: @dandavis Hi, yea the adapter should have. It's surprising that the adapter failed on a circuit with merely sensors and buzzer

Comment: My guess is that your project has a short circuit somewhere, and you are overloading your power supplies. Check the resistance on the power inputs to your project, and use ohms law to figure out how much current it would draw from the power supply at 9V